# I cannot understand the module of the python

Tags: python, numpy, file, import, module

Thankyou for helping me in advance.

What I am curious is this.

I made the File A, and in there exist module named B, and there is function C.

Then to use the C, I should type

from A import B

B.C() Something like this.

but when I use the module numpy, there is file named numpy, and there are many files and module in the numpy.

And if I just type

Import numpy

then I can use numpy.array and everything even though I didnt import any module.

I also want If I just import the file A, then I can use the function C.

How is it possible? Sorry for my poor English..

Comment: I have no idea what it is that you find confusing, but it is probably better if you read a tutorial.

Comment: I can't guess what you mean by "I made the File A, and in there exist module named B". The file does not "contain" modules, it implements them - a single module per file, and if your file is `a.py` then your module is named `a`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Sorry for my poor English.. I wanted to say that I made a 'folder', (not 'file') A, and in the folder there is B.py module, and in the module there is function C. As you know, I can command  " import A ". but I cannot use function C even I import A. but when I import folder 'numpy', then I can use the module and function in the module in the folder numpy. I just wanted to know how does it work. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should import it initially as:

```
from A import B.C
```

That should help